# How to put date into navigation title?

Tags: swift, calendarkit

I am studying on swift, and I have a project using CalendarKit.
I want to put date into navigation title so that can change current date while swiping.
But I have no idea on it...

Answer (score 1):

Its very simeple:
Step I- Write below code in **viewDidLoad()** fucntion to set **navigationTitle**.

```
self.navigationItem.title = "\(Date())"
```

Step II- You can change **navigationTitle on swiping** by using same code in your swiping action.

Eg:

```
func onSwipeChangeTitle() {
   self.navigationItem.title = "\(Date())".  
}
```